# Is my average power logic correct?

Tags: rms

Original question I am trying to solve:

> [image: Image of question text]

*This question is from "Fundamentals of Electric Circuits", 7th Edition from Sadiku and Alexander*

For this question, capacitors don't have average power so the average power there would be 0. The resistor would have average power though and here is where I feel uncertain. To find the average power of the resistor, would you convert the ac current into a rms value and then use that rms voltage value to find average power for the resistor?

This method gets me to the correct answer of 213.34W however, what I don't understand if my working is valid is how you can convert an ac signal into a dc signal in a question and apply it just like that to the resistor which is in an ac circuit. Basically, how can you apply a dc voltage in an ac circuit to find the average power in a resistor?

Answer (score 1):

The RMS of an AC  signal represents the DC that would give the same power in a resistive load.

So RMS is not giving actual DC it is pretend DC, or equivalent DC.

One way to confirm that this wirks would be to take the time
integral of the power dissipasted by a fixed resistor over one
cycle of an arbitrary waveform and then cancel out the resistance,
and cancel out the duration of the time interval  you will be left with a expression that should be easily proven to be the same as the RMS.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to see why by looking at the following instantaneous power curve (from Desmos web-plotting) for the resistor:

[image]

You can see that the approximate average is likely to be a little above \$200\:\text{W}\$, just by eye. (The peak is exactly twice the value you calculated, in fact.)

But I've also colored in two different sections which obviously must have the same area in them, which is another way of telling you that the average dissipation will be half the peak.

The dissipation obviously varies moment to moment. But at this frequency and given a resistor able to dissipate this much heat the peaks and valleys will be averaged into a dissipation that acts as if there were a DC source of some value (the one you calculated.) But you could just use \$\frac12\frac{160^2}{60}=213.\overline{3}\$. (You could also use calculus to compute the same result, but doing it by summing instant by instant.)

Note also that the power varies at twice the frequency of the applied cosine voltage source:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> what I don't understand if my working is valid is how you can convert
> an ac signal into a dc signal in a question and apply it just like
> that to the resistor which is in an ac circuit. Basically, how can you
> apply a dc voltage in an ac circuit to find the average power in a
> resistor?

The right thing to do is always calculate with the U(t) and I(t) and get a momentary power P(t). But this is complicated and we EEs are lazy and want a quick shortcut. If you  are out in the field you do not want to sit down and solve an integral but quickly get a number.

$$ U(t)=\hat{U} cos(\omega t) $$
$$ I(t)=\hat{I} cos(\omega t) = \frac{\hat{U}}{R} cos(\omega t) $$
$$ P(t)=U(t)\cdot I(t) = \frac{\hat{U}^2}{R} cos^2(t) = \hat{P} cos^2(t) $$

Average over one period $$ \omega T = 2\pi $$
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_0^{2\pi} cos^2(\alpha) \, d\alpha = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_0^{2\pi} \frac{1+cos( 2 \alpha)}{2} \, d\alpha = \frac{1}{2} $$

(where the hat above the symbols stands for "peak")

So the average power over one period is 1/2 the peak power.

$$ \bar{P} = \frac{\hat{P}}{2} $$

(where the bar over P stands for "average")

The same power would be caused by a DC voltage and DC current of:

$$ U_{RMS} = \frac{\hat{U}}{\sqrt{2}}  $$
$$ I_{RMS} = \frac{\hat{I}}{\sqrt{2}}  $$

Then conveniently

$$ U_{RMS} \cdot I_{RMS} = \frac{\hat{U} \cdot \hat{I} }{ \sqrt{2} \sqrt{2} } = \bar{P} $$

So this way you can conveniently continue to calculate with the RMS to get power ratings without doing the integration.

The RMS then also works for different curves then sine if you calculate the "root means square"

$$ U_{RMS} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T} \int\limits_0^T  (U(t))^2 dt } $$

This depends on the wave form. Typically you know the ratio of peak to RMS for certain wave forms and then use it to calculate the power.

Answer (score 0):

> *would you convert the ac current into a rms value and then use that
> rms voltage value to find average power for the resistor?*

You have an RMS voltage of 113.137 volts across a 60 Ω resistor. That's a power of 213.333 watts.

- Note 1 113.137 is the peak voltage (160 volts) divided by the square root of 2
- You can divide by \$\sqrt2\$ to get the RMS voltage because the waveform is sinusoidal
- Note 2 Power equals voltage squared divided by resistance